# CVMetalTextureCacheCreate arguments

Tags: ios, metal, core-video

Anyone knows what [`textureAttributes`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456774-cvmetaltexturecachecreate) argument for? Acceptable keys and values for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header file CVMetalTextureCache.h, near where cache attributes such as `kCVMetalTextureCacheMaximumTextureAgeKey` are defined, there's this comment:

```
// textureAttributes - reserved for future use
```

And nothing's defined there. So, apparently there are no acceptable keys or values.

Answer (score 0):

> kCVMetalTextureCacheMaximumTextureAgeKey
>   By default, textures age out of the cache after one second. To disable the age-out mechanism completely, set a maximum texture age of zero.

[Apple Documentation -> Core Video -> CVMetalTextureCache -> Cache Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvmetaltexturecache/cache_attributes?language=objc)

sample of usage:

```
NSDictionary *cacheAttributes = @{
                                      (NSString*)kCVMetalTextureCacheMaximumTextureAgeKey: @(0),
                                      };
```